# Is it possible to execute tasks on the Namenode?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

I am using spark with HDFS and yarn, so basically spark running on hadoop. I use the yarn-client mode to run tasks on the cluster. By default the tasks execute on the data nodes of the cluster. However, I would also like the namenode to execute some tasks, as it sits idle all the time. So, is it possible to also have the namenode execute some of the tasks? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be more specific, Spark tasks are not running on Datanodes. When running Spark on Hadoop the tasks are executed on the Nodemanagers which are the execution units in hadoop/yarn cluster runniong on each slave node on Hadoop/Yarn cluster. But in general in Hadoop/Yarn cluster on each slave node there are the two processes DataNode and NodeManager

The equivalent of Namenode (the master of datanodes) with Nodemanager is the Resourcemanager (which is the master of nodemanagers)

The Namenode/ResourceManager themselves could not execute any task, they are just the Master processes which manage the slaves (datanode and nodemanagers respectively)m unless you have started nodemanager process on the same host running the Namenode (or ResourceManager)

If you mean by NameNode the physical node where the Namenode process starts, yes you could, as soon as you start the Nodemanager process on that node.